# Material UI: Select is collapsed, autoWidth not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

The Material UI (React) Select item is collapsed and doesn't auto expand in width despite `autoWidth`.

[image]

```
   <FormControl margin="dense">
          <InputLabel id="prefix-label">Prefix</InputLabel>
          <Select
           autoWidth
           labelId="prefix-label"
           id="prefix"
           disabled={formPrefix.disabled}
           value={formPrefix.value ?? ""}
           error={formPrefix.invalid}
           defaultValue={""}
           label="Prefix"
           onChange={handlePrefix}
          >
                 <MenuItem value={""} disabled>
                        Prefix
                 </MenuItem>
                 <MenuItem value={"US"}>US +1</MenuItem>
                 <MenuItem value={"else"}>Else</MenuItem>
          </Select>
          <FormHelperText></FormHelperText>
   </FormControl>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: autoWidth affects the width of the "popover" an will bee set according to the items inside the menu. It has nothing to do with the width of your `Select`

Comment: @NizarZizoune I see. And why is it collapsed then? Something wrong with the placeholder? After I select an item, it adjusts the width.

Comment: I think this one has to do with the width of your `Select`, something related to your layout/css.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `width` property to `sx` prop of `FormLabel` like:

```
<FormControl margin="dense" sx={{ width: 100 }}>
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-rgb-6sydz) for live working example.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `fullWidth` props on `<FormControl>` component instead of on the `<Select>` component.

Your JSX code has to be like this

```
<FormControl margin="dense" fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="prefix-label">Prefix</InputLabel>
  <Select
    // autoWidth
    // fullWidth
    labelId="prefix-label"
    id="prefix"
    //  disabled={formPrefix.disabled}
    //  value={formPrefix.value ?? ""}
    //  error={formPrefix.invalid}
    defaultValue={""}
    label="Prefix"
    //  onChange={handlePrefix}
  >
    <MenuItem value={""} disabled>
      Prefix
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"US"}>US +1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={"else"}>Else</MenuItem>
  </Select>
  <FormHelperText></FormHelperText>
</FormControl>
```

Edit this code in the **[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-thunder-q8t7t?file=/src/App.js)**